# glProgramUniformMatrix3fv not work excepted

Tags: python, opengl, glsl

I'm using python3.6.7 with opengl 3.2.

I use `glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(program, location, count, transpose, value)` functoin. However, when I input some data in it, it report that `value` should be 12 bytes, but I think it should be 3*3*4=36bytes.

Error as flowing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opengl_program_pipline_exampled_debug.py", line 67, in <module>
    gl.glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(VP, loc_matrix,1, True, matrix)
  File "latebind.pyx", line 32, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__ (src/latebind.c:989)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 299, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__ (src/wrapper.c:6294)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 161, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculator.c_call (src/wrapper.c:4241)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 128, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call (src/wrapper.c:3601)
  File "wrapper.pyx", line 114, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call (src/wrapper.c:3409)
  File "arraydatatype.pyx", line 421, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.AsArrayTypedSizeChecked.c_call (src/arraydatatype.c:8869)
ValueError: ('Expected 12 byte array, got 36 byte array', array([ 0.98480775, -0.17364818,  0.        ,  0.17364818,  0.98480775,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]), None)
```

And I try `glProgramUniformMatrix4fv`, it reports that `value` should be 16 bytes, but I think it should be 4*4*4 = 64bytes.

It seems that it receive a vec{3,4} instead of mat{3,4}.

Is this a bug of python wrapper?

Here is my test code:

```
#!/bin/python3
import glfw
import OpenGL.GL as gl
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
import numpy as np
import pyquaternion

vertex_code = '''
#version 150
in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 rotate_matrix;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
'''python3

glfw.init()
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
window_size = (800, 800)
window = glfw.create_window(*window_size, "test", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

VS = shaders.compileShader(vertex_code, gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

VP = shaders.compileProgram(VS, separable=True)

L1 = gl.GLuint()
gl.glGenProgramPipelines(1, L1)
gl.glUseProgramStages(L1, gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, VP)

data1 = np.float32(
    (
        (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (-0.5, 0.5, 0.0),
        (-0.5, -0.5, 0.0),
    )
)

vbo1 = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1)
gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data1.nbytes, data1, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

vao1 = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
gl.glBindVertexArray(vao1)
loc_position = gl.glGetAttribLocation(VP, "position")
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc_position)
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(loc_position, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, True, 4*3, None)

while True:
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    gl.glBindProgramPipeline(L1)
    loc_matrix = gl.glGetUniformLocation(VP, "rotate_matrix")
    matrix = pyquaternion.Quaternion(axis=(0,0,1), degrees=10).rotation_matrix.ravel()
    gl.glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(VP, loc_matrix,1, True, matrix)
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao1)
    gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 3)


    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()
```

Comment: "*Is this a bug of python wrapper?*" Yes. OpenGL *itself* has no idea how big the array you give it is.

Comment: _"I'm using python3.6.7 with opengl 3.2."_ `glProgramUniform*` is not in GL3.2, it is part of GL4.1 or `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects`

Comment: Thank you. I use `from OpenGL.GL.ARB import separate_shader_objects
` to import this library, and use `    separate_shader_objects.glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(VP, loc_matrix,1, True, matrix)`.  
 Howerver, it still expect a 12 bytes data instead of 36 bytes. Must I change GL3.2 to GL4.1?

Comment: Ok, I write a demo which works in GL3.2. [click here](https://gist.github.com/lihao2333/4e2863b5be3d65a8d9901a0cd5934511)

Comment: Where's your fragment shader?  They aren't optional in Core contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I was similarly confused by the way the function takes in the data and here are my results from the experiments I ran on this function.
The function `glProgramUniformMatrix3fv` indeed takes in a matrix (3x3) but the way you pass to the function is through the [* operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) which unpacks the matrix.

For example,

```
matrix = np.array([(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0 ,1)], dtype=np.float32) # 3x3 identity
glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(Vertex_shader, uniform_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, *matrix)
```

Here Vertex_shader is the shader program, uniform_loc is the location of the matrix uniform that you pass to the shader. This seemed to work for me.

If you do this instead:

```
glProgramUniformMatrix3fv(Vertex_shader, uniform_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, matrix)
```

you get the error "ValueError: ('Expected 12 byte array, got 36 byte array'...."

This is similarly the case for all other `glProgramUniformMatrix*fv` functions.

Disclaimer: I am still learning and am simply sharing the thing that worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: Python's `*`-operator denotes iterable unpacking instead of "pointer". More about that in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).